# AngularJS number input that ignores all keys but numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to create an input in an AngularJS template and that will only accept whole numbers as input. That is, I don't want it to allow any keys other than 0-9, specifically, I can't stop `.` from being allowed in the input.

[Alexander Puchkov created a directive](https://codepen.io/apuchkov/pen/ILjFr) that achieves this on inputs with `type="text"` however I want to be able to use `type="number"` so I can maintain all my other attributes on the field for validation such as min, max, step, etc.

I have an example of this [directive not working on a number input here](https://codepen.io/mattjegan/pen/JMrryP). For example, when `type="text"` an input of `123.` yields a rendering of `123` however when `type="number"` an input of `123.` yeilds `123.` since the previous value of `123` is equal when compared numerically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid this simply isn't possible as the following condition is true:

```
0. == 0
```

If you perform the following:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(element[0].value), 100))
```

It will always log **0.** as **0**. This is why ngModelCtrl isnt triggering the parser as no changes are detected.

I would suggest not directly modifying the value of ngModel (as this can also end up leading to users putting in invalid data. ie. pasting 12.00 will resolve to 1200 with your example)

I would add a directive that applies validity depending on if a decimal point is **used** (technically speaking, typing **0.** isn't actually *using* it. **0.01** is). Set the validity to false if there is a decimal point in the number and display an error message accordingly (via ngMessages). This way the user can correct their own error and can learn from the mistake.

Comment: While this seems to be true the last sentence reminds me of "you're holding it wrong" :)